# how to write a for loop to combine several data frame that are made with forward pipe operator in R?

Tags: r, for-loop

I need to make a new dataframe but I don't know how to use for loop to reduce the repitition.

This is my original data frame

```
ID t1 t2 t4 t5 t6
1 S B 11 1 1
1 S B 11 2 0
1 S B 12 3 1
1 S B 12 4 1
1 S B 13 5 0
1 S B 14 6 1
1 S B 14 7 1
1 S B 15 8 0
2 S B 11 1 1
2 S B 12 2 1
2 S B 13 3 1
2 S B 14 4 0
2 S B 15 5 1
3 S G 11 1 1
3 S G 12 2 1
3 S G 12 3 0
3 S G 13 4 0
3 S G 14 5 1
3 S G 15 6 1
4 S G 11 1 1
4 S G 12 2 0
4 S G 13 3 0
4 S G 14 4 1
4 S G 15 5 0
5 N B 11 1 1
5 N B 12 2 1
5 N B 13 3 1
6 N B 11 1 1
6 N B 12 2 1
6 N B 13 3 1
6 N B 13 4 1
6 N B 14 5 0
6 N B 15 6 1
7 N G 11 1 0
7 N G 12 2 1
8 N G 11 1 0
8 N G 11 2 1
8 N G 11 3 0
8 N G 12 4 1
8 N G 12 5 0
8 N G 13 6 1
8 N G 13 7 1
8 N G 13 8 1
8 N G 14 9 1
8 N G 14 10 0
8 N G 15 11 1
8 N G 15 12 1
8 N G 15 13 0
8 N G 15 14 0
```

The following is the code I have written to extract my new data frames:

```
t=levels(as.factor(df$t4))

df11<- df %>%
  filter(t4==11) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(num=seq_along(ID)) %>% 
  as.data.frame

df.11.new<- df11 %>%
  group_by(t2, num) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(t6), count=n())

df.11.new$t7="d11"
```

I need to repeat this  code for all the levels of t4, which are "11", "12", "13", "14" and "15"

and finally combine them all like the following code:

```
df.all<-rbind(df.11.new, df.12.new, df.13.new, df.14.new, df.15.new)
```

But I don't know how to write a for loop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `filter`ing, add 't4' as grouping, then we don't need multiple `filter` in a loop and then `rbind` the outputs

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df.all <- df %>% 
   group_by(ID, t4) %>% 
   mutate(num = row_number()) %>%
   group_by(t4, t2, num) %>%
   summarise(mean = mean(t6), count = n(), 
      t7 = str_c('d', first(t4)), .groups = 'drop')
```

-checking with OP's output for `t4 = 11`

```
> df.all %>% 
   filter(t4 == 11)
# A tibble: 5 × 6
     t4 t2      num  mean count t7   
  <int> <chr> <int> <dbl> <int> <chr>
1    11 B         1   1       4 d11  
2    11 B         2   0       1 d11  
3    11 G         1   0.5     4 d11  
4    11 G         2   1       1 d11  
5    11 G         3   0       1 d11  
> df.11.new
# A tibble: 5 × 4
# Groups:   t2 [2]
  t2      num  mean count
  <chr> <int> <dbl> <int>
1 B         1   1       4
2 B         2   0       1
3 G         1   0.5     4
4 G         2   1       1
5 G         3   0       1
```

---

If we use the `rowid` from `data.table`, can remove the first grouping

```
library(data.table)
df %>% 
  group_by(t4, t2, num = rowid(ID, t4)) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(t6), count = n(), 
     t7 = str_c('d', first(t4)), .groups = 'drop')
```

Comment: Thanks, How do I add the final line then?  df.11.new$t7="d11"

Comment: @akrun, is `group_split` an option here?

Comment: @TarJae you could do that, but then you may need `map` to loop

Comment: @Pegaah Also, just wanted to say that if this t7 is just 'd' added, you can change the name of 't4' in group_by to t7 i.e. `group_by(t7 = str_c('d', t4), t2, num = rowid(ID, t4)) %>% summarise(mean = mean(t6), count = n(), .groups = 'drop')`

Comment: Thanks but this data frame was a simplified version of my original data frame, so the d should be day1, day5, day7 etc. therefore I can not use this part of the code yet.

Comment: Thanks, would you please help with another question again,
I used your following code
`library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df.all <- df %>% 
   group_by(ID, t4) %>% 
   mutate(num = row_number()) %>%
   group_by(t4, t2, num) %>%
   summarise(mean = mean(t6), count = n(), .groups = 'drop')`
This is exactly what I needed, but now I need to change the members of t4, in this way: where it is "11", I want it to be "d1", "12" to be  "d5", "13" to be "d8", "14"  to be "d11" and "15" to be "d22".

So the question is how to change the specific rows of a specific column in a  data frame?

Comment: Okay I find out how to solve it. `df.all$t4[df.all$t4 == "11"] <- "d1"` , `df.all$t4[df.all$t4 == "12"] <- "d5"`, etc.

Comment: You could have changed it as `%>% mutate(t4 = as.character(factor(t4, levels = 11:15, labels = c("d1", "d5", "d8", "d11", "d22"))))`